# A strange trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

In [this paper](https://kundoc.com/pdf-a-robust-double-exponential-formula-for-fourier-type-integrals-.html), equation (4.5), the authors state the trigonometic identity

$$
\sin\left( \frac{n\pi }{1-\theta}  \right) = (-1)^{n} \sin\left( \frac{n\pi \theta}{1-\theta}\right)
$$
Nothing like it is on Wikipedia's list of trigonometric identities. How can we prove this?

Comment: It probably uses: $1- \frac{1}{1-\theta}= \frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$ so it's shifting by $\pi$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:

Just write
$$\sin\left( \frac{n\pi }{1-\theta}  \right) =\sin\left( \frac{n\pi(1-\theta + \theta) }{1-\theta}  \right) = \sin\left(n\pi + \frac{n\pi\theta}{1-\theta}  \right) $$

Now, apply the addition formula for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$.